# Changing Google Datastore api version

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a project hosted on Google app engine and it is using datastore api version v1beta2. Can anyone please suggests the step how to migrate from api version v1beta2 to version v1?
I got a mail from google asking to move to datastore api version v1 as v1beta2 is deprecated and will stop working after September 30.

Please help as I am unable to work this out since last 2 days.

Thanks

Comment: What runtime language are you using? Is it PHP?

Comment: Also - are you possibly using Dataflow?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @DanMcGrath . Yes,The runtime language is PHP.

Comment: No problem. What client library are you using to access Cloud Datastore? Is it PHP GDS by any chance? https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds

Comment: @DanMcGrath The client library used is : google-api-php-client
Thanks

Comment: What version of google-api-php-client are you using?

Comment: Thanks @WillHayworth for you response.
I was able to complete the upgrade with modifying the orm accordingly for latest version of library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are most likely using the [PHP GDS client library](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds). Versions 2.x essentially uses v1beta2 as a gateway, whereas [3.x stream](https://github.com/tomwalder/php-gds#using-the-datastore-rest-api-v1-sep-2016) does not.

Upgrading your client library to the latest will start sending requests via the supported path rather than the deprecated path.